# Connect to a remote RHEL VM via ssh and sudo

Tags: jprofiler

I have installed JProfiler 10.0.1 on my local Windows 7 and a remote RHEL 7 VM.

Due to formatting issues, output pertaining to point-3 is provided here :

```
bash-4.2$ hostname
l4513t.sss.se.com
bash-4.2$ ./jpenable
Select a JVM:
org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi start [29714] [1]
org.apache.nifi.NiFi [29731] [2]
2
Please select the profiling mode:
GUI mode (attach with JProfiler GUI) [1, Enter]
Offline mode (use config file to set profiling settings) [2]
1
Please enter a profiling port
[45180]
45180
You can now use the JProfiler GUI to connect on port 45180
bash-4.2$
```

Some facts:

1. The remote RHEL JVMs that I wish to monitor run with a user 'nifi'
2. Since I am a 'sudoer', I use my own username 'ojoqcu' to SSH(via Putty) to the remote VM and then a '**sudo su - , su nifi**' or simply '**sudo su nifi**'. Then, I become the 'nifi' user without providing a password
3. As per the [jprofiler documentation](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/), **I executed the 'jpenable' file as 'nifi' user**, following is the output

When I try to connect from my local machine to a 'Remote Application' using the JProfiler wizard, I get the connection error. Note that manually providing the port 45180 didn't help as the user running the jprofiler is nifi.

[image: SSH_Connection_Details]

[image: sudo su nifi]

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that manually providing the port 45180 didn't help as the user running the jprofiler is nifi.

If you have already run jpenable, this is what you should do. Instead of using the "Discover running JVMs" you use the "Manually specify profiling port". In that case there will be no issues regarding users other than in the context of setting up the SSH connection to the remote machine.